# Download images for google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to build a batch image downloader in chrome. Basically, i will overlay a small download square to each image on the page and user clicks on it to download. Or the user can click to download all images on a page. I'm currently stuck on figuring out how to download the images. The best i can come up with is to use XHR to send the image to another server, the user can then retrieve it there.

If anyone have a solution for me. It would be much appreciated!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can XHR the images and using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) you can store them locally.

Take a look at the following site http://www.html5rocks.com/features/file there are additional resources on the right column that has detailed examples and tutorials. Such as http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Mohamed Mansour

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the trick for you: https://gist.github.com/1049553
It's very simple usage of a 'feature' in chrome when you open an image in a new tab.

Comment: I think ido shifts out of the question - to save rather to open